# Import Woocomerce product variation into magento 1.9 configurable products via CSV

Tags: configurable-product, import, products

Hello I need some information on how to set my CSV file to import configurable products in magento.

I am using Data Flow Profile to export the sample product I created in magento. But I cant find a columnn for configurable products.

What column should I enter the data of my product variation from my Woocomerce to magento configurable products?

Comment: You might use import/export, which supports configurable products:
http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Magento data flow doesn't support the import/export for other than simple product by default.

I occasionally use this tool: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-bulk-product-import-export-with-tier-pricing-product-custom-options-configurable-products-bundle-products-grouped-products-downloadable.html

You can find the sample CSV [here](http://www.commerceextensions.com/docs/extension_import_export_products_sample_csvs.zip) and documentation [here](http://www.commerceextensions.com/docs/extension_import_export_products_documentation.pdf).

Note that I am not associated with the company and this is based on my experience with the extension.

Comment: Can it export products from Wordpress Woocomerce??